# Add items to a dataframe if item in column already present

Tags: pandas

Other than brute forcing it with loops, given a `dataframe` **df**:

```
   A       B    C  
0  True    1    23.0
1  False   2    25.0
2  ...     ...  ....
```

and a `list` of `dicts` **lod**:

```
[{'A': True, 'B':2, 'C':23}, {'A': True, 'B':1, 'C':24}...]
```

I would like to add the first element of the **lod** `{A: True, B:2, C:23}` because 23.0 is already in the **df** C column, but not the second element `{A: True, B:1, C:24}` because 24 is not a value in the `C` column of **df**.

So add all items of the `list of dicts` to the `dataframe` on a `column` value already being in the dataframe, otherwise continue to the next element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert list of dict to a data frame , then using `isin`

```
add=pd.DataFrame([{'A': True, 'B':2, 'C':23}, {'A': True, 'B':1, 'C':24}])

s=pd.concat([df,add[add.C.isin(df.C)]])
s
Out[464]: 
       A  B     C
0   True  1  23.0
1  False  2  25.0
0   True  2  23.0
```